# Python tkinter - rename a treeview item

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am making a user interface with tkinter's treeview and one thing that I want to be able to do with it is to allow the user the ability to change the names displayed by the items whenever they want. However, from what I can tell from the documentation, the function that could do this, `set` only allows for column values to be changed.

Is there any way to change the text of a treeview item without deleting it and remaking it?

Comment: `tree.item(iid,text="new_text")`

Comment: Well, that worked. Thanks!